# Jenkins launching application in background

Tags: java, ant, windows-7, junit, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to launch my junit test automation. Test scripts are triggered thorough an ant build.xml. On start test script launch the application and than do the GUI testing.

If i launch my test on command prompt by issuing ant command it works fine, it launches the applicatio in foreground and test the application. But when i launch same command through jenkins, I can see my application process getting created in task manager but GUI never appears. Basically whole GUI gets loaded in memory in background and testing happens as it should.

I am using windows 7.

I am not sure why this difference in behavior, any help direction or pointer to solve the problem is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also at the end of build I see following statement: Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of GUI application were you testing? SWing, Win32?

One thing about GUI test with Jenkins is you should not run the slave process as a service.

--

Make it clearer, please launch the slave machine which the GUI test cases runs with JNLP.

Comment: getting same issue with win32, I am running Jenkins as well as application on same server, which is aws ec2 instance on Win server 2012 R2 Standard

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andy for the reply, yes it is a Swing application and as you rightly pointed that was the issue.
I was running the Job with Master which is configured as service. I created a new slave and started it with JNLP and application GUI appeared.

Thanks, for the reply